# Инжектирование dll в Qt-приложение

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, dll

На данный момент бьюсь над решением следующей задачи: необходимо внедрить dll в Qt-приложение, а затем получить Qwidget для дальнейшего взаимодействия с ними. Перепробовал/перечитал много информации. Через Qt-creator создаю своё приложение и внедрение происходит успешно, а вот в стороннее никак не получается. Очевидно, что-то делаю неправильно. Если у кого есть подобный опыт, пожалуйста, покажите код по подобным внедрениям. Буду очень благодарен!

**Код инжектирования:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char const path[] = "TestLibrary.dll";

void setDebugPrivilege()
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES privileges;
    privileges.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    privileges.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to open process." << std::endl;
    }

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(0, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &privileges.Privileges[0].Luid))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to look up privileges." << std::endl;
    }

    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, false, &privileges, sizeof(privileges), 0, 0))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to adjust token privileges." << std::endl;
    }

    CloseHandle(hToken);
}

int main()
{
    setDebugPrivilege();

    HWND hWnd;
    hWnd = FindWindowA(0, "MainWindow");

    if (!hWnd) 
    {
        std::cout << "Could not find editor window." << std::endl;
    }

    DWORD pId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pId);

    if (!pId) 
    {
        std::cout << "Could not find process id." << std::endl;
    }

    HANDLE hProcess;
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, pId);

    if (!hProcess) 
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to open process." << std::endl;
    }

    HANDLE allocatedAddress;
    allocatedAddress = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, 0, sizeof(path), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    BOOL result = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (void*)allocatedAddress, (void*)path, sizeof(path), 0);

    HANDLE hRemoteThread;
    hRemoteThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA"), allocatedAddress, 0, 0);

    if (!hRemoteThread) 
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create remote thread: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(hRemoteThread, INFINITE);
    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, allocatedAddress, sizeof(path), MEM_DECOMMIT);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    system("Pause");

    return 0;
}
```

**Код dll на Qt:**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "testlibrary.h"

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved);

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            TestLibrary test;
            test.Test();
            break;
        }
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        {
            break;
        }
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

P.S. Всё это было найдено на просторах интернета. Но видимо каких-то знаний мне не хватает, чтобы довести дело до успешного завершения

Comment: У приложения может быть защита от инъекций.<br> Попробуйте вместо открытия процесса `OpenProcess(...)` создавать требуемый процесс с флагом `CREATE_SUSPENDED`, делать инъекцию и потом возвращать управление процессу через `ResumeThread(...)`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но в процесс без проблем внедряется скажем обычная c++ dll (можно увидеть через Modules её присутствие в процессе-жертвы), а в случае c qt dll, то ли точку входа DllMain не видит, то ли какая-то другая проблема... Если у вас есть рабочий код по этой теме, то я даже готов заплатить.